# How do I check If sub category of category x in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

Is there a way that I can check using a conditional whether the page is a subcategory of a specific category ?

i.e: on my 'category.php' I currently have:

```
 <?php } else if (is_category( 'blog' )) { ?>
```

This is to render a different view depending which category page the user is on.

Is it possible to do something like ?

```
 <?php } else if (is_sub_category_of( 'blog' )) { ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Although very old, I've created the perfect solution.

Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
/** check if the current category is a child of a given category **/
function current_cat_is_sub_of($parent = ''){
    global $wp_query;
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1.0' );
        return false;
    }
    elseif( $cat->parent!=0 && $cat->parent == $parent ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it various ways. For example to change the displaying order of posts in all subcategory pages under a given category:

```
/** order posts under category 123 from new to old **/
function order_digital_posts($query){
    if (current_cat_is_sub_of('THE PARENT CATEGORY ID') && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'order_digital_posts');
```

Enjoy!
Itamar

Comment: This is cool. Is it possible for `current_cat_is_sub_of()` to include grandchildren as well? `Parent > Child > Grandchild`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I stumbled on this last night and I had to find an answer for myself.

This is on my `category.php` page:

```
$category = get_the_category();

if(isset($category[1]) && $category[1]->slug === 'catagory-you-want') {

    // Do stuff if it's a child of "Category You Want"
    // You can use $category[1]->cat_ID to check which category instead

}
```

The current subcategory is in `$category` at position `0`.

This would be harder if "Category You Want" had a parent category and you didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if your current category parent id matches the "blog" category id. If so, your current category is a subcategory of "blog".

```
$current_cat = get_query_var("category");
$cat = get_term_by('slug',$current_cat,"category");
$blog = get_term_by('slug',"blog","category");


if($cat->parent == $blog->ID){ /*your code */ }
```

This code will do the functionality you described.